# Conflict between packages com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.jsonschema and com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.jsonSchema

Tags: java, eclipse, jackson, jsonschema, jackson-modules

I have a problem incorporating both the [jackson-module-jsonSchema-2.1.0.jar](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.module/jackson-module-jsonSchema/2.1.0) and [jackson-databind-2.1.5.jar](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-databind/2.1.5) libraries into my project.

I'm using Eclipse on Windows and I have created a new "Plug-in from Existing JAR Archives" project, containing both the jackson-module-jsonSchema-2.1.0.jar and jackson-databind-2.1.5.jar as dependencies.

The problem is the following:

- in the project created there is only the package `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.jsonSchema`
- the package `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.jsonshema` is missing

I suppose this is due to the fact that the two JARs (jackson-module-jsonSchema-2.1.0.jar and jackson-databind-2.1.5.jar) contain code in two similar paths -
`com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/jsonschema` and `com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/jsonShema`respectively. The two paths are different only in upper and lower case (s vs S) and on Windows the path of packages is case insensitive.

How can I solve this problem? Thanks.

Comment: Whoever named the packages in `jackson-module-jsonSchema` should be shot. They have created (potential) naming conflicts all over the place.

Comment: What @Perception said. Is it possible for you to change that code so that the packages are named reasonably by, say, requesting a change or creating a PR (from what I see, Jackson is open sourced on GitHub), or maybe using different versions that have reasonable naming conventions?

Also, in your post, one is named jsonschema, and the other jsonShema (without the 'c').